# Controller Not receiving value from span in HTML using Spring boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following content in my HTML which is using `Thymeleaf`

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/shutDown}" th:object="${ddata}" method="post">
        <span>Domain</span>
        <span th:text="${domain}" th:field="*{domain}">domain</span>
        <input type="Submit" value="close" />
</form>
```

And I have the following in my `Controller` which is using `Sprint Boot`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shutDown", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView shutDownPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, Authentication authentication,
        @ModelAttribute("ddata") DInputBean dInputBean) {
    String domain = dInputBean.getdomain();
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I'm hoping I'd get value of `domain` from the HTML in the `Controller` but it's always null. `DInputBean` has `getters and setters` for "domain" field.

Comment: I believe `th:field` should be used on `<input>` elements.  You could place a hidden input field inside the span.

Comment: @jmw5598: How do I do that? Sorry I'm not used to front end code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Are you looking to just add some text to the page and a button?  Or do you need to an input field on the front-end with a button?  Or both?

Comment: @bphilipnyc: sure. I'm trying to display a value  called `domain` on the page using `<span>`. Then after clicking on the `close` button (which is inside a form as well) the `/shutDown` controller should receive the value of the `domain`

Comment: Ok, then the Edit: answer from @jmw5598 will be sufficient,  ut the key thing is to add the value of `domain` to the page using a `@GetMapping` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `th:field` attribute can be used on `<input>`, `<select>`, or, `<textarea>`.

A solution you could possibly replacing you second `<span>` with a hidden input element.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/shutDown}" th:object="${ddata}" method="post">
    <span>Domain</span>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{domain}" th:value="${domain}" />
    <input type="Submit" value="close" />
</form>
```

If you wanted to keep the second div, just place the `<input type="hidden">` inside the second `<span>` and remove the `th:field` attribute from the second `<span>`.

#### Edit:

If you wanted to add the value of `domain` in a span.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/shutDown}" th:object="${ddata}" method="post">
    <span>Domain</span>
    <span th:text="${domain}">domain<span>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{domain}" th:value="${domain}" />
    <input type="Submit" value="close" />
</form>
```

> http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs

Comment: I need to also display the value of ${domain} on the page. Having only `<input>` with type `hidden` won't display right? In that case can I also add the other `<span>` tag to display the `${domain}`?

Comment: Yes, the hidden field will not display any text.  You can add a `<span>` to display the value of `domain`.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use a read-only input field:

```xml
<input type="text" th:field="*{domain}" th:value="${domain}" readonly="readonly"/>
```

This both displays the value and sends it on submit.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to add the value of the `domain` variable to the form:

```
@GetMapping("/shutDownPage") 
public String shutDownPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("ddata" new Ddata()); //or however you create your bean
    String username = ... //however you get your username
    String domain = myRepositoryService.findDomainByUsername(username);
    model.addAttribute("domain", domain);
    return "shutDownPage";
}
```

Include an HTML page in the `action` so that when you open the HTML page in a browser without a server/container, the button will still appear to work:

```
<form action="confirmationPage.html" th:action="@{/shutDown}" th:object="${ddata}" method="post">
     <!-- You can benefit from using a conditional expression -->
     <span th:text="${domain != null ? domain : 'No domain supplied'}">[domain]</span>
     <input type="hidden" th:field="*{domain}" th:value="${domain}"/>
     <input type="Submit" value="close"/>
</form>
```

And your post method:

```
@PostMapping("/shutDown")  //use shorthand
public String shutDownPagePost(@ModelAttribute("ddata") DInputBean dInputBean {
    String domain = dInputBean.getDomain();
    //do whatever with it
    return "confirmationPage";
}
```

Comment: I also store the domain in database. So I used `Authentication` `authentication.getName()` to get the user name and then queried the database using `JPA` and got the domain name. This is what I did. But your suggestion is something on the front end. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Ok, so instead of "stackoverflow.com" in the answer above, you would simply replace it with the domain name that you get from the database.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm also fine with you giving `@jmw5598` the checkmark since that's really the crux of the answer.